# How to calculate probability that normal distribution is greater or equal to some value in R?

Tags: r, probability

I'm interested in calculating the probability that the standard normal distribution is greater than **or equal** to some value x. How can this be done?

I understand that `pnorm(x)` calculates the probability of getting a value smaller than or equal to x, and that `1-pnorm(x)` or `pnorm(x, lower.tail=FALSE)` calculate the probability of getting a value larger than x. I'm interested in the probability for a value either larger or equal to x.

Thanks!

Comment: I think, with continuous probability, less than or equal is the same as less than?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal distribution is a continuous distribution. Therefore the probability of being greater than x and the probability of being greater than or equal to x are the same (similarly the probability of being less than x and the probability of being less than or equal to x are the same)

Therefore

```
# P(X > x) = P(X >= x)
1 - pnorm(x)

# or
pnorm(x, lower.tail=FALSE)
```

Both of these are equivalent (however they may occasionally provide different answers due to the numerical solver).